# use tensorflow mnist can't recognize my number

Tags: python, tensorflow, mnist

This is the first example of the tensorflow Library.
It's correct rate is about 91%.
But I have a problem when I recognize my own numbers.

```
#python3
import tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist.input_data as input_data
import tensorflow as tf
import os
os.environ['TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL'] = '3' 
mnist=input_data.read_data_sets("MNIST_data/", one_hot=True)
from PIL import Image,ImageFilter
x=tf.placeholder(tf.float32,[None,784])
w=tf.Variable(tf.zeros([784,10]))
b=tf.Variable(tf.zeros([10]))
y=tf.nn.softmax(tf.matmul(x,w)+b)
y_=tf.placeholder(tf.float32,[None,10])
cross_entropy=-tf.reduce_sum(y_*tf.log(y))
train_step=tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.01).minimize(cross_entropy)
sess=tf.InteractiveSession()
tf.global_variables_initializer().run()
for _ in range(1000):
    batch_xs,batch_ys=mnist.train.next_batch(100)
    sess.run(train_step,feed_dict={x:batch_xs,y_:batch_ys})
print(prediction.eval(feed_dict={x:[l]},session=sess)[0])
correct_prediction=tf.equal(tf.argmax(y,1),tf.argmax(y_,1))
accuracy=tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction,tf.float32))
print(sess.run(accuracy,feed_dict={x:mnist.test.images,y_:mnist.test.labels}))
img=Image.open("b3.jpg").convert("L")
img=img.resize((28,28),Image.ANTIALIAS).filter(ImageFilter.SHARPEN)
imgArr=img.getdata()
l=[i/255.0 for i in imgArr]
prediction=tf.argmax(y,1)
print(prediction.eval(feed_dict={x:[l]},session=sess)[0])
```

[My handwritten numerals](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6XVKv.jpg)

[Program execution result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ivC4p.jpg)

My handwritten number is 3 but the result is 2?

Comment: what? how about writing 100 numbers and then evaluating the accuracy? are you really asking why it fails with 1 example?

Comment: I use the drawing tool to write the numbers, the correct recognition rate is very low.@dv3

Comment: 91% is low? What's the question here? Why isn't the model perfect?

Comment: 91% success is MNIST test data. The success rate of my own handwriting is low.@dv3